# How do I use get_mol() on a pdb file in RDKIT-JS?

Tags: javascript, bioinformatics, rdkit

I want to convert a pdb file into a morgan fingerprint repersentation using RDKIT-JS. There is no documentation on how to do this. The function doesn't accept pdb format, but it can use json, no documentation on how to go from pdb to json. Does anyone know a way you can do this?

I have tried entering the pdb file, returns null. Using smiles it works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.